# Standard practice/API for sharing database data without giving direct database access

Tags: database, api, interface

We would like to give some of our customers the option to read data from our central database. The data is live and new records are being added every few seconds. Our database is MySQL running on Amazon RDS.

I was wondering what is the common practice for doing so.

One option would be to give them select right from specific tables, in that case they would be able to access other customers' data as well.

I have tried searching for database, interface, and API key words and some other key words, but I couldn't find a good answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use REST for exposing specific tables to do CRUD operations. You can control the access on it too.